# solution to $\text{div}(f)=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, divergence-operator

What is the most compact representation of the general solution to
$$
\text{div}(f)=\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}+\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x_2}+\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x_3}=0
$$
for a $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ that goes to zero exponentially as $|\vec{x}|\to\infty$.

My first approach was the Helmholtz theorem with a potential that satisfies the Laplace equation.
Edit: Using the Helmholtz theorem,  $f=-\nabla \Phi + \nabla\times f$,   one can write
$$
\nabla\cdot f = -\nabla^2 \Phi + \nabla\cdot \nabla\times f=-\Delta \Phi =0 
$$

Comment: Why must the vector potential satisfy Laplace? The general form of $f$ (without the decay condition) is $f = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}$ for any vector potential $\mathbf{A}$. I'm guessing, but it sounds like $\mathbf{A}$ decaying exponentially should be sufficient for $f$ to decay exponentially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Poincar'e Lemma, as in Spivak's Calculus on Manifolds, includes
the fact that for smooth functions ( $x$ and $f(x)$ in $R^3$, domain
of $f$ a star-shaped set) you have
$$
 f(x) = {\rm curl\,}\Big(
 \int_0^1 f(tx)\times tx\,dt
                    \Big)
 +\int_0^1 t^2x{\rm \, div\,}f(tx)\,dt.
$$
(I have changed the notation to express it for vector fields; Spivak
has it for differential forms.)

When the divergence of $f$ is zero in a star-shaped set there are many
functions $g$ such that $f = {\rm curl\,} g$; the first integral
above is one of them.

It looks like we can't guarantee the exponential decay:
Suppose $|f(x)| \le ce^{-|x|}$. Then
$$
 \bigg|
  \int_0^1 f(tx)\times tx\,dt
 \bigg|
  \le
  \int_0^1 ce^{-t|x|}t|x|\,dt
$$
$$
 =\bigg[
 -c\big(t+\frac{1}{|x|}\big)e^{-t|x|}
 \bigg]_0^1
 =
 c\Big(-\big(1+\frac{1}{|x|}\big)e^{-|x|}+\frac{1}{|x|}
 \Big).
$$